# variable refrenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
    if item.lower() == "slots":
        res = await sell_this(ctx.author, item, 1)

        if res[1] == 3:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have slots machine in your bag.")
            return

        if not res[0]:
            if res[1] == 1:
                await ctx.send("That Object isn't there!")
                return
            if res[1] == 2:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return
            if res[1] == 3:
                await ctx.send(f"You don't have {item} in your bag.")
                return

        users = await get_bank_data()
        emojis = ""
        a = random.choice(emojis)
        b = random.choice(emojis)
        c = random.choice(emojis)
        bad = random.randrange(250, 1000)
        good = random.randrange(500, 2500)
        amazing = random.randrange(2500, 7500)

        slotmachine = f"**[ {a} {b} {c} ]\n{ctx.author.name}**,"

        if (a == b == c):

            await ctx.send(f"{slotmachine} All matching, you won {amazing} coins! ")
            users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += amazing

        elif (a == b) or (a == c) or (b == c):

            await ctx.send(f"{slotmachine} 2 in a row, you won {good} coins ! ")
            users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += good
        else:

            await ctx.send(f"{slotmachine} No match, you lost {bad} coins  ")
            users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= bad

        with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
```

Ok, so everything works very well but everytime i try to use the command it send so if i win or lose or whatever and it gives me this error

**Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment**

Comment: You are using `user.id` but you didn't define `user` anywhere in this code.

Comment: Because the code has `users[str(user.id)]`, and where is user variable defined?

Comment: What about user.id? I don't see it declared it anywhere?

Comment: I havent defined a variable called user

Comment: Then maybe you should look at the stack trace instead of asking strangers on the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your code, I assumed you want to do something like `users[str(ctx.author.id)]["wallet"]` instead of `users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]`

Comment: Omg i forgot my bad bro its 9 am and i havent slept yet